# How to get command block talking in chat to nearby players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get a command block to write in the chat, and it is working, but it is displaying it to all players in the server. I only want the chat to appear to the player that steps on the pressure plate. Ive tried everything from `@p` and `@s`.

example of text I try is below

```
/tellraw @p {"text":"Hello World!"}
```

but that tells it to every player. I've tried

```
/tellraw @p[distance=3] {"text":"Hello World!"}
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: No, a command that starts with `/tellraw @p` does not do anything for **every** player. How did you test this? And in what version are you playing?

Comment: I tested this at a spawn in a public server and I'm playing 1.14.4 Other players are saying they are receiving the chat message far away from spawn. I'm not sure why this is happening

Comment: Wait never mind, turns out some of the command blocks were @a, i'm dumb lol

Answer (score -1):

Well, “distance” isn’t a tag, use `r` instead.

Also, `@p` would only do one player, so use `@a`. This would make

```
/tellraw @a[r=3] {“text”:”Hello World!”}.
```

Comment: I have a pressure plate that's on top of the command block so I'm trying to make it is  for whoever steps on the plate. And I've tried r=3 too and it still doesn't work

Comment: Wait never mind, turns out some of the command blocks were @a, i'm dumb lol

Comment: `distance` is the "new" variant of `r`, which allows for multiple new features. I put "new" in quotation marks, because this was changed almost two years ago. If you haven't played the game for this long, please don't answer without checking what you're saying. And your `@p` vs. `@a` advice is exactly the opposite of what the asker wanted.